# Both pieces of code add light but what difference does it make if I use the first one and not the latter one?

Tags: python, scripting, objects

```
bpy.ops.object.light_add(type='SPOT', location=(0,0,0))

######
light_data= bpy.data.lights.new(name="Spot_light", type= "SPOT")
light_data.energy= 10

light_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name="Spot_light", object_data=light_data)
```